# C++ Operator overloading, returns, types and robots

Tags: c++

```
Node& operator += (const Node& node);   //Append
```

I have this operator declaration and i am a bit confused, i am coming from C background and kinda late to c++ party. Function returns a reference to this, here is some code.

```
Node& Node::operator+=(const Node& node)
{
    std::cout << "Operator: +=" << '\n';
    return *this;
}
```

Now usage example:

```
    Node x;
    Node n; 
    n += x;
```

So the question is, when n+=x happens, operator is called, but then return value is never used, no copying happening, no moving. i am just a bit lost.

Comment: @MooingDuck that actually makes some sense :)

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, you can also do this:

```
void foo(int copy_of_n) {}
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int n = 4; 
    foo(n += x);
}
```

The expression `n+=x` does the increment and assignment, and then "returns" `n` for further usage.

Likewise, in C++:

```
void foo(Node& reference_to_n) {}
int main() {
    Node x = {3};
    Node n = {4}; 
    foo(n += x);
}
```

The expression `n+=x` does the increment and assignment, and then "returns" `n` for further usage.

Comment: It's pretty rare to use the "return value" of `+=`, so it's easy to forget.